# Unable to resolve target 'google inc.:google apis:19

Tags: android, sdk, eclipse-plugin

I installed api level 19 in my sdk but yet my project is not able to run and display error 
unable to resolve target 'google inc.:google apis:19' can any one tell me how to solve this issue?thnks in advance